# Microsoft visual studio не грузит компоненты

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio

Помогите, пожалуйста, не грузит компоненты windowsforms, абсолютно любые, скачивал, загружал, всегда одна и та же ошибка. В первый день работы в этой программе я смог подгрузить Bunifu Ui, Компоненты работали, на следующий день они перестали работать, и не могу подгрузить другие библиотеки компонентов. На другом пк или ноуте эти компоненты грузятся на ура. Visual studio удалял и устанавливал - не помогло.

[image: вот сам скриншот ошибки.]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Потому что ваш MaterialSkin возможно имеет версию .net core, а не .net framework. Ну это я так предполагаю, но вы посмотрите у себя в проекте

Comment: Пробовал и там и там, и в WPF даже.

Comment: Сам решил данный вопрос, Дело в том, что ругался антивирусник.. Попробовал его отключить - сразу же все заработало, еще можно было решить проблему - перетаскиванием файла DLL в панель элементов в Visual studio Drug and drop' ом. Надеюсь, кому-то помогу этим...